# SEO: Is it OK to collect information from different websites and display on one page?

Tags: seo, duplicates, search-engine

My teacher advised me to create a platform where information about specific topics around the web should be displayed at one place. For example, If there are a lot of topics around the web  about Android Tutorials.

1. I will choose the top 20 (or any number of) websites.
2. I will create a page for android tutorials on my website
3. I will mention the most useful topics on my page, with the same titles, and same description (no full description, but just first 3-5 lines).
4. Below short description of each topic, I will create a link (read more), which will lead to the actual website for full reading.
5. The above scenario will look like the search results in a website, which have title, short description and link to topic.

So, I think, I have explained it clearly what I want to develop. But before moving forward, I want to know, Is this OK ? Will search engines love my website, or will dislike because of duplicate content? Should I move forward, or stop ?

Comment: Is it legal?  Depends on where you live and where its hosted.  If in real doubt, consult a lawyer.

Comment: @GabeSechan what do you mean by this? Is the title of my topic is not correct or something else ? I mean to ask, will search engine like this way, or will dislike ? I think, I should ask an SEO expert, not a Lawyer.

Comment: You asked if it was legal  "But before moving forward, I want to know, Is this legal ".  I'm saying that its a complex question and the answer is based on where you live and the local laws.  As for whether search engines will like it-  people won't like it, you make our search results worse.  Sites like that provide no value if they aren't providing new material.

Comment: @GabeSechan ok, but there are RSS feeds, that are about the same thing. RSS also provide no new material, but are used to display content of other websites, and links to them. Then why RSS are considered good for SEO. Is there any difference between RSS feed and the way that I have described above in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the rights. Generally all body of work is copyrighted, whether it is designated with (C) or not.

Creative Commons licensing is good for this as CC licence usually says what you can and can not do with a particular site and it's content.

Overall copyright rules allow you to take snippets, and portions but not the whole work, and it is recommended to:
1. Give attribution (link, etc)
2. Contact the author for permission

As a note, this is why Google can operate because it shows you a little bit of the website, but doesn't give you all of the website on it's own site.

In your case, my recommendation is to find Creative Commons based sites. If not, then always link back and never use all of the information, only snippets or small portions.

Note... more your content is duplicate less results you will get from Search Engines, more unique, more better.

If you have a dynamic site, then the link attribution and using only x amount of words can work.

If you have a more manual site, then having a writer to write is going to be better. I use [www.imglory.tryamillion.com](http://www.imglory.tryamillion.com)

Comment: thanks for replying. However, I have searched on web and found that this technique is called Mash-up (not sure 100%). There is a detailed article about it on Wikipedia. So, my question is, Is the technique I described really Mashup?

Comment: @MuhammadSohail yes that can be considered an old version of mashing. Mashing today would be a dynamic site that does that automatically. In your case sounds like you just starting in IM and it's a good way to start.

Comment: You are right, and I am also going to create it in a way that will find the information automatically. I will create crawler, that will search different websites for some specific topics that will match my topic on my website and will reference all the matched topics and will back-link them. What do you say about it? Is it good to do?